# Sentiment140 in Restclient Not working

Tags: c#, rest

The below code is for api call using restclient...But  it is not getting response any one have idea about this?

```
var client = new RestClient("http://www.sentiment140.com");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.Resource = "api/bulkClassifyJson";
request.AddParameter("appid", "abcd@gmail.com");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(text);
var response = client.Execute(request);
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Sentimental> items = serializer.Deserialize<List<Sentimental>>(response.Content);
return items;
```